# redirect error message to file - shell

Tags: shell

I am trying to redirect and view all my error messages from a compile to error.txt
According to my book it can be done in this way.

```
$CC error.cpp > error&1 | more
```

but however it only creates a blank file but did not store the error messages. what have I done wrong?

p.s i did purposely make my server.cpp can't compile so that it will display some error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is printed to `stderr` and not `stdout`

Try

```
$CC error.cpp 2> error
```

File descriptor 0 represents `stdin`
File descriptor 1 represents `stdout`
File descriptor 2 represents `stderr`